# Problema con readlines()

Tags: python

Estoy intentanto analizar un arhcivo csv, que contiene las características de distintos vehículos. El archivo es el siguiente:

> "Type","MPG","Date","Time","Vehicle","Odometer","Filled Up","Cost/Gallon","Gallons","Total Cost","Octane","Gas Brand","Location","Tags","Payment Type","Tire Pressure","Notes","Total Cost","Services"
>
> "Gas","0.0","2009-11-12","6:55 AM","Suzuki
> S40","3480","Full","$2.629","1.427","$3.75","87","Caseys","Decorah","","Visa","0.0","","$3.75",""
>
> "Gas","56.1","2009-10-28","4:13 PM","Suzuki
> S40","3400","Full","$2.729","2.200","$6.00","87","Kwik
> Trip","","","Visa","0.0","","$6.00",""
>
> "Gas","54.5","2009-09-07","8:03 PM","Suzuki
> S40","3280","Full","$2.459","1.914","$4.71","87","Caseys","Decorah","","Visa","0.0","","$4.71",""
>
> "Gas","52.2","2009-08-23","3:44 PM","Suzuki
> S40","3180","Full","$2.529","1.429","$3.61","87","Caseys","Decorah","","Visa","0.0","","$3.61",""
>
> "Gas","53.9","2009-08-03","6:35 PM","Suzuki
> S40","3103","Full","$2.589","1.232","$3.19","87","Caseys","Decorah","","Visa","0.0","","$3.19",""
>
> "Gas","52.8","2009-07-21","10:53 AM","Suzuki
> S40","3038","Full","$2.379","1.536","$3.65","87","Caseys","Decorah","","Visa","0.0","","$3.65",""
>
> "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

Lo que quiero es extraer de cada registro el segundo dato (galones por milla) y el tercero (la fecha). Para ello he intentado abrir el archivo y utilizar la funcion "readlines()" para guardar cada línea como un elemento de un fichero. El código que utilizo es muy sencillo:

```
file = open("SuzukiS40.csv")
lineas = file.readlines()

file.close()
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me saltan los siguientes errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguien me puede ayudar a averiguar por qué no funciona si es un código muy simple y solo esto intentando leer cada línea de un archivo?

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser un problema de encodings. Por defecto Python intenta leer los ficheros como utf8. Excel en cambio tiende a guardarlos como cp1252. Prueba a añadir al `open()` el parámetro `encoding="cp1252"`. De todas formas, para leer y procesar csv te recomiendo encarecidamente que estudies y utilices pandas.

Comment: `readlines()` lee todo el archivo de una. Si el archivo es grande, tendrás problema de memoria.

Comment: @abulafia muchas gracias, pero acabo de intentarlo poniendo encoding="cp1252" pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. ¿se te ocurre algo más?

Comment: @CandidMoe el archivo csv solo tiene 7 líneas por lo que no creo que sea problema de memoria.

Comment: El archivo csv es realmente el que has pegado como texto en la pregunta? De ser así el problema es incomprensible para mi, puesto que lo que has pegado solo contiene caracteres ascii y ninguno no-ascii que pudiera causar problemas de encoding. Por otro lado, la imagen que has adjuntado con las líneas en que ocurre un error no es de mucha ayuda. Sería más útil el _stacktrace_ que python te imprime en la consola cuando "rompe" (es un largo mensaje que incluye contexto sobre qué estaba intentando hacer y qué excepción se produjo)

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el fichero csv que tienes a algún almacén en la nube (dropbox, gdrive, onedrive...) y compartir el enlace al mismo para poder bajarlo y examinar si tiene algún byte "raro" que esté dando problemas? Se trata de subir el archivo tal cual está en tu ordenador, no de copiarlo y pegarlo (pues la operación de copy&paste podría hacer desaparecer el problema)